# How can I prevent the debugger from entering my method when Exception is thrown?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

How can I prevent the debugger from entering my method when an exception is thrown, instead show the exception at the method's call site?

For example, if one's code causes an exception to be thrown from mscorlib, the debugger (obviously) does not take them into the non-user code to show the exception's source, only shows the exception at the call site.

In other words, this the default behavior:

[image: default behavior]

and this is my desired behavior:

[image: desired behavior]

I have tried adding `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` and `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attributes to my `Fail()` method, but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to decorate your method with [DebuggerHiddenAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[DebuggerHidden]
public static void Fail() {
    throw new Exception("Fail");
}
```